# Error 1062 (23000 at line 13192: Duplicate entry ‘default-0-payment/stripe_payments/payment_flow’ for key ‘CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH'

Tags: magento2.4.5, stripe

To migrate Magento2 site to other server, I dump my db and import the db on the new server. But I get this error.

**Error 1062 (23000 at line 13192: Duplicate entry ‘default-0-payment/stripe_payments/payment_flow’ for key ‘CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH'**

I tried remove and reinstall StripeIntegration_Payments module but still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the SQL query to get this config value for later reference:
   `` SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'payment/stripe_payments/payment_flow' AND `scope_id` = '0'; ``
2. Run the SQL query to remove this config from the database to prevent the duplicate:
   `` DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'payment/stripe_payments/payment_flow' AND `scope_id` = '0'; ``
3. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.
4. Check and compare the current config with the result in the first step, then edit it manually if needed:
   `` SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'payment/stripe_payments/payment_flow' AND `scope_id` = '0'; ``

---

If you see a similar new error, you should use the below solution to work with all Stripe Integration Payments `stripe_payments` configs:

1. Run the SQL query to get the config values for later reference:
   `` SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'payment/stripe_payments/%'; ``
2. Run the SQL query to remove the configs from the database to prevent the duplicate:
   `` DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'payment/stripe_payments/%'; ``
3. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.
4. Check and compare the current configs with the result in the first step, then edit them manually if needed:
   `` SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'payment/stripe_payments/%'; ``

Comment: Awesome answer! Right, I got similar errors. So I deleted all the table-related stripe_payments as you guided. After that, I could import db without db. Thank you for much! 

Comment: You're welcome @Yohan . I'm glad to help!